# understanding: converting from int address to char array

Tags: c++

What does this line do exactly?

`(char*) (&input)`

I know that it converts the int(input) to char array..or am I wrong? and could you guide me how does it compute?

update:
I think I now understand a little, then I created c++ code from your comments

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(){
 int input = 123456;
 int *p = &input;

 char *cp = (char*)p; 

for(int counter = 0;counter <sizeof(input); counter++){        
        cout << *(cp+counter) << endl;
        }


 system("pause");
 return 0;
}
```

but i think my code is wrong. because it only shows '@' , big 'r'? , and something like cross sign ...

Comment: How is `input` declared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just casting the address of `input` as a pointer to a `char`. You might see something slightly different like:

```
unsigned char *bytes = (unsigned char*)&input;
```

Which is useful for reading single bytes at the address of `input`, since `char` is a byte in size. Note that `char` is signed and ranges from -128 to 128 while `unsigned char` is (obviously) unsigned and more appropriate for reading bytes as it's unsigned and ranges from 0 to 255.

You could then read specific bytes like:

```
first_byte = bytes[0];
```

Or perhaps you might want to set specific bytes such as:

```
bytes[0] = 0x7E;
```

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't "convert" anything. You're simply pointing at the first byte of the integer.

If your `int` is 32 bits (4 bytes), and you have a pointer to it ...

```
int myInt = 123456;
int *ptr = &myInt;
```

Then you cast that pointer to `char` pointer ...

```
char *cPtr = (char*)ptr;
```

You now have a char pointer pointing at the first byte of your integer. You can see each byte individually via:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(int); i++)
{
    printf("%d\n", *(cPtr+i)); 
}
```

Note that `char` is signed, so some bytes might wrap to negative numbers. Using `unsigned char` instead would change that behavior. If the pointer arithmetic confuses you, you can replace `*(cPtr+i)` with `cPtr[i]` and get the same output.

Comment: You *really* need to pay attention to the code I posted above. You're missing `*` in several very important places. An `*` in a declaration means you're declaring a pointer.

Comment: Your code in your edit is converting the bytes to their printable character equivalents (from your default character set, probably UTF-8) because you're sending them to `cout` and they are of type `char *`. You actually have to cast the byte to an `int`  if you're sending it to the `cout` stream: `cout << (int)*(cp+counter) << endl;`

Comment: how do i get it to print in its byte equivalent

Comment: See the edit to my last comment: `cout << (int)*(cp+counter) << endl;`

Comment: i got 64 , -30, 1, 0 <-- if i solve this manually into bits then this is the actual bits that the (stream to file.txt) is working on?

Comment: That is correct - those are the 4 bytes in the integer `123456`. As noted, if you change all the `char` to `unsigned char` you won't get the (wrapped) negative value from the second byte.

Comment: Note that you should prefer `static_cast` to C-style casts in such scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

If `input` is an integer then it reads the block of bytes at that address as if they were (presumably signed) characters.

so if input had the value 1234567890 then (ignoring details like byte ordering) the char* would point to the values 0x49 0x96 0x02 0xD2

Answer (score 1):

It takes the address of the integer (a pointer-to-int) and converts the pointer into a pointer-to-char.  You can then use that pointer to read the bytes of the integer one at a time.

Comment: yes i did get 0x22ff44..i still dont get it.. how is it going to read the bytes? could you make an example please :)

Comment: int i = 12345;
const char * pi = (const char *) &i;
for (int i=0; i<sizeof(i); i++) printf("byte #%i of the integer is:  0x%02x\n", i, pi[i]);